# IndexError: index 1080 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1080

Tags: python, opencv

I am reading through frames of a video on python and I am trying to finding the RGB of each frame index. I need to detect the LED(put a threshold for on/off - red/black) but I am encountering problems with indexing.

I need to access the RGB values on the left down quarter of the image.

```
# Check if camera opened successfully
if (video.isOpened()== False): 
  print("Error opening video stream or file")

  # Read until video is completed
while(video.isOpened()):
  # Capture frame-by-frame
  ret, frame = video.read()
  frame_read += 1

  if ret == True:

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)

    height, width, channels = frame.shape

    #Accessing RGB pixel values    
    for x in range(round(width/2), width) :
     for y in range(0, round(height/2)) :
          print(frame[x,y,2], frame[x,y,0], frame[x,y,1], frame_read) #R,B,G Channel Value


    # Press Q on keyboard to exit
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break

  # Break the loop
  else: 
    break

    video.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My error is on the line print(frame[x,y,2], frame[x,y,0], frame[x,y,1], frame_read) 
    IndexError: index 1080 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1080

Comment: first guess is that you're dealing with a 0 based index -- in which case 1079 would be you're highest value -- if that fails you can add a print statement showing the current value inside your for loop to see what the last value available is before it throws the error

Comment: Could you be more precise please? Add some lines of code I need to fix. I am quite new on this spectrum.

Comment: if you read all error message then you should see which line make problem and where to use `print()` to see value in variable. If error say you have `IndexErrors` then you have to check variables which you use in `[ ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you sliced the frame as `frame[x, y, 2]` you forgot that the first slice of `frame` is always height (as you did correctly in `height, width, channels = frame.shape`) so the x you are referring to in the frame slicing can't range from `0` to `width` (1920 in your case) because the first slice(your `x`) has range from `0` to `height` (1080).

Same goes for `y` that references the width (so ranges from 0 to 1920 in your case).

Just swap the frame slicing and you are good to go:

`print(frame[y,x,2], frame[y,x,0], frame[y,x,1], frame_read)`

Comment: @abcdef The problem is not in the order of the channels.
I'll try to make myself clear:
the frame is shaped always with height first, width second and channels third as you correctly did in `height, width,channels = frame.shape`.

Basically the frame is an array so when you are slicing the array as `frame[x, y, channel]` your `x` is the height and your `y` is the width while the channel is correct.  
In the two for loops you are looping through your 'x' with the width index but `x` as you referenced it in the slice is ,in reality, the height so it can't go over the `height` maximum index

Comment: you can fix the issue in two ways:  

1. `print(frame[y,x,2], frame[y,x,0], frame[y,x,1], frame_read)`

or

2. swap x and y in the for loops