# index 1920 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1080

Tags: python, opencv

[enter image description here][1]I am working in a opencv program and i get the error: "index 1920 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1080". w is equal to 1920 and when i change it to 1079 it works.

```
import cv2            #opencv, computer vision
import time   #import time

pTime = 0  #iniziating variable time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("segment4_pumping_and_foiling.mp4") #open the video
cv2.namedWindow("video", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)   #full screen
cv2.setWindowProperty("video", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN) #full screen

while True:    #while the video is playing
  success, img = cap.read()  #read the video link
  
  h, w, c = img.shape  #parameters of the images

  cTime = time.time()  #obtain the time
  fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime) #calculate frames per second
  pTime = cTime      #restart the timer
  cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (70, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,(255, 0, 0), 3) #write it in the window
 
  ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,206,210,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
  
  i=1
  point0=(0,h)
  pointw=(w,h)
  for i in range(200):
    (b0, g0, r0)=thresh[0,(h-i)]
    (bw, gw, rw)=thresh[w,(h-i)] #deberia ser hasta el wide, no 1079
    if (b0>200 and g0>200 and r0>200): #and flag0=0
      #flag0=1
      point0=(0,h-i)
    if (bw>200 and gw>200 and rw>200):
      #flagw=1
      pointw=(w,h-i)
  
  image = cv2.line(thresh, (0, 830), (w, 830), (0, 255, 0), 4)
  image = cv2.line(thresh, point0, pointw, (0, 255, 255), 4)

  #cv2.imshow("video", img)  #show the video
  cv2.imshow("video", thresh) 

  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): #if you write 0 (frame by frame), quit pressing q
    break   #close the video window

cv2.destroyAllWindows()  #clear
cap.release()      #clear
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IndexError: index 1080 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1080](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57878978/indexerror-index-1080-is-out-of-bounds-for-axis-0-with-size-1080)

Comment: Sounds like you've got your dimensions mixed up.

Comment: Even with the dimensions in the right order, you'd still be trying to access a pixel that's just outside the bounds of the image.  Either subtract 1 from both coordinates, or use `img[-1, -1]` to access the lower-right pixel without having to know the image size.

Comment: I am taking the colours of a pixel of the image, so I want to take the pixel that is most on the right side, taking the width of the image. Which is the dimension problem?

Comment: When I use img[-1,-1] it does not work correctly, it does not take the point more in the right side

Comment: The error is in  (bw, gw, rw)=thresh[w,(h-i)]

Answer (score 1):

Two issues I can see - for one, pixels are 0-indexed. So for an HD image (1080x1920), the bottom right pixel is (1079, 1919).

In addition, you access an opencv image/Mat by [row][col]. So the last line should be:

`(b, g, r) = img[h-1,w-1]`

Comment: I am able to right (b,g,r)=img[1079,h] but if I draw the point, the heigh it is on the bottom but the width is not the top right, it is just the 1079 pxl

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are saying by 'it is just the 1079 pixel', but I'll try help. Opencv uses a top-left origin. So [0,0] is the pixel in the top left, and (in an HD image) [1079, 1919] is the BOTTOM-right pixel. So, to access / draw on the bottom right, use [1079, 1919], or [height - 1, width - 1]. 

If you want the top right pixel, use [0, 1919], or [1, width - 1]

Comment: As you said in your comment above, the error is in 'thresh[0,(h-i)]' and 'thresh[w,(h-i)]'. You need to swap these around so it is 'thresh[h-i,0]' and thresh[h-i, w - 1]